# Creating toolbar can not be Locked

Tags: eclipse, rcp, e4

Inside Application.e4xmi -> Trimbars -> Toolbar there is no mechanism to lock the toolbar to make it unmovable.  Is this not available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the value `NoMove` to the Tags for the Toolbar control (on the Supplementary tab)

[image: NoMove value]